# Iterate over columns of a DataFrame and assign values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a one-column DataFrame (data), indexed by ordered dates, and I want to create a second DataFrame with p columns, and assign to each column a shifted version of data. I.e., I want in to see in the first column data.shift(1), in the second column data.shift(2), etc. My implementation is as follows:

```
lagged_data = pd.DataFrame(index = data.index, columns=[i+1 for i in range(p)])
for i in range(p):
    lagged_data.iloc[:,i] = data.shift(i+1)
```

However, after the execution only the first column is updated, while all the others remain filled with np.nan. See below the result (with p=3):

```
print(lagged_data.head())

           1   2    3
Date                 
gen-75   NaN NaN  NaN
feb-75  0.03 NaN  NaN
mar-75  0.04 NaN  NaN
apr-75 -0.04 NaN  NaN
mag-75  0.04 NaN  NaN
```

Oddly enough, by repeating one more time the same loop, ALL columns are populated correctly. I really can't see the reason of this behaviour, I have also tried to create a copy by doing

```
 lagged_data.iloc[:,i] = data.shift(i+1).copy()
```

but this gives the same result as before

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Assign series to series

You are assigning a dataframe to a series. While this gives a result, you shouldn't *expect* this to work. Instead, assign a series to a series and use `pd.Series.shift`:

```
data = pd.DataFrame({'A': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]})

lagged_data = pd.DataFrame(index=data.index, columns=[i+1 for i in range(3)])
for i in range(3):
    lagged_data.iloc[:,i] = data.iloc[:, 0].shift(i + 1)

print(lagged_data)

#      1    2    3
# 0  NaN  NaN  NaN
# 1  1.0  NaN  NaN
# 2  2.0  1.0  NaN
# 3  3.0  2.0  1.0
# 4  4.0  3.0  2.0
```

Notice `data` is a `pd.DataFrame` object, while `data.iloc[:, 0]` is a `pd.Series` object.

#### [`pd.concat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.23.4/generated/pandas.concat.html) with a list comprehension

In this case, you can use `pd.concat` with a list comprehension instead, specifying the `keys` argument and `axis=1`:

```
res = pd.concat([data.iloc[:, 0].shift(i+1) for i in range(3)],
                keys=list(range(1, 4)), axis=1)
```

Comment: @Chris, If you're asking what happens when you assign a dataframe to a series (it gives *something*, though not correct), I'm not entirely sure. Best to keep things simple. Not everything Pandas does is documented. If it's not documented, you shouldn't rely on it as it's an implementation detail which can change in any new version.